Loading js module fails for Angular app hosted on Firebase
I have my project hosted on Firebase. When I click the url, the page does not load due to the following error:

If I then modify the url to visit another page in the project, the page loads. I can even load the home page after that, despite not being able to the first time. I do not get this error when running with ng serve. What is happening here?

what page does work fine in your app?

@Andrei pages include home page, rankings, matches, sign up, and sign in. When I paste the url into the browser, ie https://...central1.hosted.app, it should redirect from / to /home. After the home page fails to load, I can change the url to /rankings (or another page), and the page will load. Then, I can navigate to the home page (through my app) and it will load.

@Andrei when I paste the base url into a private window, the home page loads every time. But if I refresh the home page, I get the same error I've been getting. Furthermore, if I paste in https://...central1.hosted.app/home, I get the error. Really confused here.

can you try to turn off fcache in the devtools and then navigate to the app?

@Andrei disabling the cache allows the website to consistently load now.

you should then setup your firebase server to send no cache headers for index.html. the rest can and should be cached
